# Javascript array sorting problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an JavaScript arraylike this:

```
a[0][0] = "apple";
a[0][1] = 6.5;
a[1][0] = "orange";
a[1][1] = 4.3;
a[2][0] = "pear";
a[2][1] = 3.1;
```

I want to sort by the float number field in ascending order and assign the content in ascending order as well.

i.e.

```
a[0][0] = "pear";
a[1][1] = 3.1;
a[1][0] = "orange";
a[1][1] = 4.3;
a[2][0] = "apple";
a[2][1] = 6.5;
```

I have tried sorted the content but the code seems does not allow float number.

Also, I do not know how to reassign the content in ascending order.
Can anyone help me?

```
 a.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] - b[1];});
```

Comment: try a.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] > b[1];}); ? negatives value returns true, I think

Comment: What error are you seeing? That code works, at least for the main sort: http://jsbin.com/ulite3

Comment: @BiAiB: No, the function that `sort` calls is expected to return `<0` if `a` should be before `b`, `>0` if `a` should be after `b`, or `0` if they're the same.

Comment: the code you've provided has the output you wanted

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Regarding your comment to my (incorrect) answer: The code shown above to set up the array would not work as it is. One would still have to do `a[i] = []` and `a = []`.

Comment: @Felix: My comment was *"He's set up the array correctly (just verbosely), at least as far as we can tell from the code he quoted."* (Note the bit at the end; I've inferred that unless there's an error being thrown, he's set up each level.) I've called that out in my answer, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Provided the parts of your code that you haven't quoted are correct, that should work

```
var index;
var a = [];  // inferred

a[0] = [];   // inferred
a[1] = [];   // inferred
a[2] = [];   // inferred

a[0][0] = "apple";
a[0][1] = 6.5;
a[1][0] = "orange";
a[1][2] = 4.3;
a[2][0] = "pear";
a[2][3] = 3.1;

a.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[1] - b[1];
});

for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
  display(a[index].join());
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ulite3)

Output:

```
pear,3.1
orange,4.3
apple,6.5
```

---

**Off-topic**: A more efficient, and perhaps clearer, way to initialize that array:

```
var a = [
    ["apple", 6.5],
    ["orange", 4.3],
    ["pear", 3.1]
];
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ulite3/2)

Answer (score 2):

Did you create the array correctly?
Your sort function is correct...

```
var a=[['apple',6.5],['orange',4.3],['pear',3.1]];
a.sort(function(a,b){return a[1]-b[1]});

/*  returned value: (Array)
pear,3.1,orange,4.3,apple,6.5
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the a, b order in the sort function

```
a.sort(function(a,b){return b[1] -a[1];});
```

try this in your firebug, , dragonfly or webkit console

```
var a = [["apple",6.5],["orange",4.3],["pear",3.1]];
a.sort(function(a,b){return b[1] -a[1];});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: His code works fine; yours gives the array backward. See http://jsbin.com/ulite3 (his version).